# check if file exsist in directory by partial name and return the directory name if found (glob returns wrong)

Tags: python, glob

i need to return the directory path if by given the partial name of the file is found
doing it with python globe method returns wrong
this is what i have
./test/my/app/upgrade/sql.upgarage.script.sh

```
pathx = ./test/my/app/upgrade/
partial_name = "upgarage.script"

 for inner_dir in glob.glob(pathx + '/*' + partial_name  + '*'):
             if not os.path.exists(dir_path):
                print("...error ..")
```

what it returns in inner_dir  is the full name of the file and the full path instead of the path which in pathx .

now the case is that the file can be also inside  :

```
/test/my/app/upgrade/ver1/a/sql.upgarage.script.sh
```

and if found it should return :

```
 /test/my/app/upgrade/ver1/a/
```

what is wrong in my glob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `**` + `recursive=True` and glob will work for this.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob

```
glob.glob(pathname, *, recursive=False)
```

> If recursive is true, the pattern “**” will match any files and zero or more directories, subdirectories and symbolic links to directories. If the pattern is followed by an os.sep or os.altsep then files will not match.